# Regex- Whitespace is not working to get an integer value

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a pattern match using Regex. If the message has space after the pattern string, its getting a empty string.

```cs
string str = "studentId: 1234, Name: Hello";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"studentId:(\d*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match m = reg.Match(str);
Group g = m.Groups[1];
int Id = int.Parse(g.ToString());
```

> studentId:1234    (Working)
> studentId: 1234   (Not Working)
> studentId:     1234  (Not Working)

I need to get the value 1234 irrespective of spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to match the whitespace characters.

```cs
Regex reg = new Regex(@"studentId:\s*(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

*Details*:

- `studentId:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - one or more digits (Group 1).